# Ajax cross domain issue

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

When I am calling a cross domain request via ajax jsonp, i am getting the response, but the response going through the error callback only. any idea why?

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx/sample.com/query",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: "callback",
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});
```

Getting status code 200 and "Error" alert.
Any suggestion?

Comment: How do you know you're getting the 200 status code?

Comment: Are you wrapping the response in your callback function?  I think that happens when you dont set the response properly.

Comment: @Pekka: I can see 200 response code in the network tab corresponding to my request

Comment: @asafreedman: wrapping the response in the callback function need to happen in the server side, right ? I think which is causing the alert "Error"

Comment: What does the response look like?

Comment: @Pekka웃 some thing like this
{
  "data" : [ {
    "name" : "name1",
    
  },
  {
    "name" : "name2",
    
  },
  ]
}

Comment: The problem is likely to be there so you should edit the exact result into your question